# Вопрос по методу invokeAll() интерфейса ExecutorService

Tags: java

Небольшой пример с методом **invokeAll()** интерфейса **ExecutorService**:

```
public class Example {
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Callable<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            count++;
            list.add(new Callable<String>() {
                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception {
                    return "Задача номер: " + count;
                }
            });
        }
        List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(list);
        futures.forEach(k -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(k.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

В консоль выводится почему-то такой результат:

```
Задача номер: 10
Задача номер: 10 и т.д.
```

Как сделать, чтобы выводило: Задача номер: 1, Задача номер: 2 и т.д., по порядку? И, если не трудно, поясните пожалуйста, в чём причина неверной работы программы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в анонимном внутреннем классе вы ссылаетесь на статическую переменную, которая к моменту старта всех потоков равна 10 для всех объектов Callable. Самый простой выход - создавать в блоке цикла вспомогательную effectively final переменную и ссылаться уже на неё:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    count++;
    int tmp = count;
    list.add(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
           return "Задача номер: " + tmp;
        }
   });
}
```

правда это начинает напоминать js-замыкания. Более правильный вариант - вынести создание Callable в отдельный класс и передавть в него счётчик как параметр:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    count++;
    list.add(new MyCallable(count));
}
...
class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private int count;
    public MyCallable(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Задача номер: " + count;
    }
}
```